# How do I get an image from a mySQL database and resize it's dimensions using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, image, resize

**UPDATE: For anyone else wondering about this, check out the comment at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php#31178**

I have images stored in a database table. They're uploaded in their original dimensions.
I can output this image to browser using PHP headers no problem (like "getimage.php?imgID=1"), but I'm stuck if I want to resize the image before it's output to the browser.

I do not want to write to a new file, I just want to get an image from the database table, and resize it (preferably in the same PHP script).

Something like this would be perfect: getimage.php?imgID=1&width=75&height=75

Can anyone tell me how I could do this in PHP?

```
    $query=  "select * from `tablename`.`photos` where `ImageID` = '".$_GET['imgID']."' LIMIT 1";
$downloadResult = SendQuery("browse",$query); // my own custom php function to connect & send a mysql query
if(is_array($downloadResult)){ //check if a row was returned
    foreach($downloadResult as $myfile) {
        header("Content-Type: ". $myfile['mime']);
        header("Content-Length: ". $myfile['size']);
        if($d=="true"){
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'. urlencode($myfile['name']).'"');  
        }
        echo $myfile['data'];
    }
```

Comment: Post the code of `getimage.php`. Also which graphic libraries have you installed on your server? And in which image formats are the images?

Comment: You shouldn't keep images inside of the database! Keep them in files and save their paths inside of the database. Databases are not meant to hold files! That's what the **Filesystem** is for!

Comment: Are you not storing images on server in some folder ?

Comment: @Truth *sigh* I know. But that's what I've got to work with for now.

Comment: @Milap The images are not stored as files in a folder but as data in a database table.

Comment: @P3tro: I added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9633988/367456).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You load the image data from a binary string (`$myfile['data']`). All you need is an image library/extension that is able to create an image object based on a binary string. For example the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) can load data from strings:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($myfile['data']);
```

You can then take any of the very many examples (including tons of them on this site already) to resize your image to your needs.

After you have resized your image, you can output it to the browser, e.g this for a PNG:

```
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

See [`imagecreatefromstring`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/imagecreatefromstring). You might find it helpful if you use a image library that does resizing with an easy interface, for example [Wideimage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/) which supports loading from a binary string as well. It's GD based:

```
WideImage::loadFromString($myfile['data'])
    ->resize(50, 30)
    ->output('png');
```

Yes, it's that simple. See:

- [Loading images](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/documentation/loading-images/)
- [Manipulating images](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/documentation/manipulating-images/)
- [Saving images](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/documentation/saving-images/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It was how to create an image from a binary string that I wasn't sure about and this helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

Please provides image re size using extension named  - [imagic](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php)

Other useful script :-

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/
- http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/
- http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/

Comment: I've tried them all and they're either not working as I want OR way too complicated for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

does it realy need to happen in php? 
there are css properties for that, like [max-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp)

Comment: I'm not aware that I can resize a background image in CSS? That's why I need to resize when the file is requested.

Comment: think this can help you http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

you can use imagemagick, like this (untested code):

```
    //your image code here
    $image_path = 'path-to-image';

    $width = null;
    $height = null;

    if(array_key_exists('width', $_REQUEST)) {
        $width = intval($_REQUEST['width']);
    }

    if(array_key_exists('height', $_REQUEST)) {
        $height = intval($_REQUEST['height']);
    }

    //add your header infos like
    header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"');
    if(null !== $width && null !== $height) {
        $cmd = 'convert '.escapeshellarg($image_path).' -resize '.$width.'x'.$height.' - ';
        echo shell_exec($cmd);
    }
    else {
        readfile($image_path);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your getimage.php script do at the moment? Does it display the image from the database in a `HTML` `img` tag? If it displays the image in an `img` tag then you could add the fields for `width` and `height` to the `img` tag to display the image at the size you require.

Comment: The getimage.php script just outputs the image to browser. In PHP I've set the header to say that the content of what's being requested is an image (see my code above for reference).